# Python pass class weights to SequentialFeatureSelector?

Tags: python, xgboost

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS
```

xgboost classifier

```
XGB = xgboost.XGBClassifier(num_class = 3)
```

Sets features selection

```
SFSres = SFS(XGB, k_features=8,cv=5)
```

Trying to pass class weights for feature selection

```
SFSres = SFSres.fit(train_data, train_labels, fit_params={'sample_weight':weights})
```

result

> TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_params'

How to pass class weights to feature selection?

Comment: Which version of `mlxtend`?

Comment: Try updating mlextend, this attribute is indeed in the docs of the latest version

Comment: @yatu 17.0 now i installing 17.3

Comment: @yatu mlxtend docs says that fit_params incluted in 12.0. my version now 17.3 and  Error "TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_params'".

Comment: Its quite weird. I reproduced without problems with `mlxtend.__version__ #'0.17.2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "the documentation is incorrect and needs to be updated"

decision:

```
fit(train_data, train_labels, sample_weight=weights)
```